# subtract the contents of one column from another columns in each row

Tags: mysql

I have a big MySQL table and I want to change the `Description` column.

I want to delete the beginning of the every cell in each row that matches the value in the `Name` column, while the rest of the cell remains the same.

Please help.
[image]

Comment: I can do it manually, but it would take me weeks to do. I hope there is an easy solution for this

Comment: Hi this can be achieved the question is the value of name column will be same in description I mean no white space or spelling mistakes

Comment: For example kobo  => kobO ?

Comment: there's hardly anything to go on here, since you didn't post the db schema nor any mysql code

Comment: Sorry I am new here, I have inserted an image description :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REPLACE** is your friend.

**use this to see the changes:**

```
SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(Deescription,`name`,'')) as newField from youtTableName;
```

**update your table**

```
UPDATE youtTableName
SET `Deescription` =  TRIM(REPLACE(Deescription,`name`,''))
;
```

Comment: The second is perfect! You saved me a week of hard work to change each cell in my phpMyAdmin. The code is working (Catalan was my table name):       UPDATE catalan
SET `Description` =  TRIM(REPLACE(Description,`name`,''))
;

Comment: Thank YOU for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use update  whete the locate for the name in desciption is 1 (at the begin of the description)

```
update my_table
set description = substr( description, length(name)+1)
where locate(description, name ) = 1
```

Comment: I would use a `like` in the where clause because it may use an index, while the function would not.